# Convertir un XmlTextWriter a String

Tags: c#, xml

tengo que generar un xml y firmarlo electronicamente, estoy ya generando el xml pero quieroevitar tener que guardarlo en disco para luego volver a leerlo y de ahi firmarlo electronicamente.
Para esto estoy usando el siguiente codigo

```
using (var xmlMemoria = new MemoryStream())
{
    string contenidoXML = string.Empty;
    //using (XmlTextWriter Wr = new XmlTextWriter(xmlMemoria,new UTF8Encoding(false)))
    using (XmlTextWriter Wr = new XmlTextWriter(xmlMemoria, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        Wr.Formatting = System.Xml.Formatting.Indented;
                Wr.WriteStartDocument();
        Wr.WriteStartElement("GTDocumento");
        ....
        ....
    }
    contenidoXML = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(xmlMemoria.ToArray());
}
```

Pero cuando hago un punto de interrupcion justo en la variable contenidoXML, y veo lo que tiene al parecer se forma el xml correctamente. el resultado es algo como esto
﻿

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dte:GTDocumento xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:dte="http://www.sat.gob.gt/dte/fel/0.1.0" xmlns:n1="http://www.altova.com/samplexml/other-namespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="0.4" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.gt/dte/fel/0.1.0 ">
  <dte:SAT ClaseDocumento="dte">
    <dte:DTE ID="DatosCertificados">
      <dte:DatosEmision ID="DatosEmision">
        <dte:DatosGenerales CodigoMoneda="GTQ" FechaHoraEmision="2019-05-21T09:58:53.000-06:00" Tipo="FACT" />
        <dte:Emisor AfiliacionIVA="GEN" CodigoEstablecimiento="1" CorreoEmisor="fsigu@hotmail.com" NITEmisor="16896327" NombreComercial="ARM" NombreEmisor="ARM MARKETING">
          <dte:DireccionEmisor>
            <dte:Direccion>Gran Colombia</dte:Direccion>
            <dte:CodigoPostal>0</dte:CodigoPostal>
            <dte:Municipio>Guatemala</dte:Municipio>
            <dte:Departamento>Guatemala</dte:Departamento>
            <dte:Pais>GT</dte:Pais>
          </dte:DireccionEmisor>
        </dte:Emisor>
        <dte:Receptor CorreoReceptor="fsigu79@gmail.com" IDReceptor="75368803" NombreReceptor="Especialidades Agricolas Manantial, S.A.">
          <dte:DireccionReceptor>
            <dte:Direccion>Especialidades Agricolas Manantial, S.A. 3ra. Avenida 02-52 Zona 1 Parramos Chimaltenango.</dte:Direccion>
            <dte:CodigoPostal>0</dte:CodigoPostal>
            <dte:Municipio>Guatemala</dte:Municipio>
            <dte:Departamento>Guatemala</dte:Departamento>
            <dte:Pais>GT</dte:Pais>
          </dte:DireccionReceptor>
        </dte:Receptor>
        <dte:Frases>
          <dte:Frase CodigoEscenario="1" TipoFrase="1" />
          <dte:Frase CodigoEscenario="1" TipoFrase="2" />
        </dte:Frases>
        <dte:Items>
          <dte:Item BienOServicio="B" NumeroLinea="1">
            <dte:Cantidad>150.00</dte:Cantidad>
            <dte:UnidadMedida>LTS</dte:UnidadMedida>
            <dte:Descripcion>MP1010.6090-Frankliniella Occidentalis</dte:Descripcion>
            <dte:PrecioUnitario>45.00</dte:PrecioUnitario>
            <dte:Precio>6750.0048</dte:Precio>
            <dte:Descuento>0.0000</dte:Descuento>
            <dte:Impuestos>
              <dte:Impuesto>
                <dte:NombreCorto>IVA</dte:NombreCorto>
                <dte:CodigoUnidadGravable>1</dte:CodigoUnidadGravable>
                <dte:MontoGravable>6026.7900</dte:MontoGravable>
                <dte:MontoImpuesto>723.2148</dte:MontoImpuesto>
              </dte:Impuesto>
            </dte:Impuestos>
            <dte:Total>6750.0048</dte:Total>
          </dte:Item>
        </dte:Items>
        <dte:Totales>
          <dte:TotalImpuestos>
            <dte:TotalImpuesto NombreCorto="IVA" TotalMontoImpuesto="723.21" />
          </dte:TotalImpuestos>
          <dte:GranTotal>6750.00</dte:GranTotal>
        </dte:Totales>
      </dte:DatosEmision>
    </dte:DTE>
  </dte:SAT>
</dte:GTDocumento>
```

Sin embargo copio ese texrto y lo pego en un editor de texto y lo grabo como un xml y al querer abrir el documento desde un explorador web no se abre, muestra como si estubiera mal formado el xml
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
De lo que pude revisar es que me aumenta signos ? al inicio del documento como lo pueden ver en la imagen anterior.

Pero si cambio un poco el codigo y en lugar de enviar a memoria lo envio a un archivo, al abrir el xml se lo muestra de forma correcta.
No se si alguien sabe que puede estar pasando ya que por eso no me deja firmar el documento xml cuando lo trabajo directo en memoria??

Comment: pero como es esa operacion que haces de copiar y pegar en el archivo? no sera que en ese momento estas copiando incorrectamente, si quieres generar ese file porque no usas `File.WriteAllText(ruta, contenidoXML);` asi te aseguras que el contenido del string se lleva al archivo sin error humano

Comment: que editor usas? porque sino es el notepad puede que otros agreguen adicional para el formato

Answer (score 1):

Lee el XML con `UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);`
El valor false le indica que no escriba la marca de orden de bytes o el BOM